# I can't rotate screen in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EkranDöndür : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
        print("this code is working");
    }

    void Update()
    {
    }
}
```

I want to use the screen horizontally in a scene of my game

I tried this code but it didn't work

How can I do it?

**

Comment: is this script attached to any gameobject in scene?

Comment: Yes. Main camera

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the orientation:

Go to Edit > Project Settings > Player it will open Player Settings in the inspector. Select the target platform from the list. Click the Resolution and Presentation section. Set the Default Orientation to Landscape left / right.19

Comment: I did what you said but nothing changed.